# How to have a nested struct as linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new in C and I have to do a project which reads data from a **.txt** file and created *linked list of structures* to different operation on that structures (CRUD). The file contains data of rooms in a hotel and its guests with below pattern:

```
---
203
1
103.52
#
Michal Novak
Malinova 97, Bratislava
20210114
20210119
---
105
2
323
#
Tomas Kovac
Jahodova 3, Bratislava
20210204
20210302
#
Lucia Kovacova
Jahodova 3, Bratislava
20210204
20210302
```

In the file each room record starts with `---` and each guest record starts with `#`. Each line of file has data of one property (different datatypes) of room or guest. I wrote below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>    
#include <ctype.h>      
#include <errno.h>      

#define FILE_NAME "hotel.txt"
#define MAXC   1024     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

typedef struct Guest {
    char* name;
    char* address;
    int beginningOfReservation;
    int endOfreservation;
    struct Guest *next;
} Guest;

typedef struct Room {
    int roomNo;
    int numberOfBeds;
    double price;
    struct Guest *guests;
    struct Room *next; 
} Room;

Room *head = NULL;
Room *current = NULL;

Guest *gstHead = NULL;
Guest *gstCurrent = NULL;

int get_file_line_count() {
    FILE *myFile;
    char line[100];
    int fileLineNumber = 0;
    myFile = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if(!myFile) {
        printf("file not opened corectly!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    while(feof(myFile) == 0) {
        fgets(line, 99, myFile);
        fileLineNumber++;
    }
    fclose(myFile);
    return fileLineNumber;
}

void insertRoom(int roomNo, int noOfBed, double price, Guest *geusts){
    Room *hotelRoom = (Room*) malloc(sizeof(Room));
    hotelRoom->roomNo = roomNo;
    hotelRoom->numberOfBeds = noOfBed;
    hotelRoom->price = price;
    hotelRoom->guests = geusts;
    hotelRoom->next = head;
    head = hotelRoom;
}

void insertGeust(char* name, char* address, int startDate, int endDate){
    Guest *gst = (Guest*) malloc(sizeof(Guest));
    gst->name = name;
    gst->address = address;
    gst->beginningOfReservation = startDate;
    gst->endOfreservation = endDate;
    gst->next = gstHead;
    gstHead = gst;
}

void n() {
    int counter = 0;
    int firstCounter = 0;
    int secondCounter = 0;
    int hashCounter = 0;
    int lineCounter = 0;
    char line[MAXC];

    FILE *fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if (!fp) { 
        perror ("file open failed");
    }

    int roomNo;
    int noOfBed;
    double price;
    char name[100];
    char address[100];
    int startDate;
    int endDate;
    while(feof(fp) == 0) {
        fgets(line, 99, fp);
        switch (firstCounter)
        {
            case 1:
                roomNo = atoi(line);
                break;
            case 2:
                noOfBed = atoi(line);
                break;
            case 3:
                sscanf(line, "%lf", &price);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (secondCounter)
        {
            case 1:
                sscanf(line, "%[^\n]s", name);
                break;
            case 2:
                sscanf(line, "%[^\n]s", address);
                break;
            case 3:
                startDate = atoi(line);
                break;
            case 4:
                endDate = atoi(line);
                break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        if (strcmp("---\n", line) == 0) {
            hashCounter = 0;
            firstCounter = 0;
            secondCounter = 0;
            lineCounter++;
            gstHead = NULL;
            gstCurrent = NULL;
            if(lineCounter > 1){
                insertGeust(name, address, startDate, endDate);
                insertRoom(roomNo, noOfBed, price, gstHead);
            }
        }
        if (strcmp("#\n", line) == 0) {
            hashCounter++;
            if(hashCounter > 1){
                insertGeust(name, address, startDate, endDate);
            }
            secondCounter = 0;
        }
        
        if (feof(fp) != 0){
            firstCounter = 0;
            hashCounter = 0;
            lineCounter++;
            if(lineCounter > 1){
                insertGeust(name, address, startDate, endDate);
                insertRoom(roomNo, noOfBed, price, gstHead);
            }
        }
        firstCounter++;
        secondCounter++;
        counter++;
    }
    if (fp != stdin){
        fclose (fp);
    }
}

void printRoom(){
    struct Room *ptr = head;
    while(ptr !=NULL){
        printf("\n%d", ptr->roomNo);
        printf("\n%d", ptr->numberOfBeds);
        printf("\n%lf", ptr->price);
        printGuest();
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void printGuest(){
    struct Guest *ptrr = gstHead;
    while (ptrr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%s", ptrr->name);
        printf("\n%s", ptrr->address);
        printf("\n%d", ptrr->beginningOfReservation);
        printf("\n%d", ptrr->endOfreservation);
        ptrr = ptrr->next;
    }  
}

int length() {
    int length = 0;
    struct Guest *curr;
    for(curr = gstHead; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next){
        length++;
    }
    return length;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char operation;
    int fileLineNumber;
    do {
        printf("\n\nSelect the operation you want to do from the following list: \n\n");
        printf("For Summary Type s\n");
        scanf(" %c", &operation);
        fileLineNumber = get_file_line_count();
        n();
        printRoom();
        // printGuest();
        // free(hotelRoom);
    } while (operation != 'x' || operation != 'X');

    return 0;
}
```

Although I searched a lot, but I have two problems which could not handle them: 1. The two attributes (properties) of Guest struct (which are string) after inserting to the linked list, on printing are always the last one in the file. I tried a lot to figure it out why this is printing the last record in file while they are the proper ones on printing the names on `insertGuest()` function but on printing them from `printGuest()` function they're always the last ones.
2. How can I have dynamic number of Guests for each Room. I mean there are cases where one room has more than one guests, how should I create separate linked list of struct of `Guest` for every Room struct depending on the number of guests in the `.txt` file. Although I figured out how should I read data from file but could not handle Guest struct insertion and linking it with each Room.The expect result is as below after printing the linked list of Room struct from `printRoom()` function:

```
    Room number: 105
    Number of beds: 2
    Price: 323
    Guests:
    Name: Tomas Kovac
    Address: Jahodova 3, Bratislava
    Reservation start: 20210204
    Reservation end: 20210302
    ###########################
    Name: Lucia Kovacova
    Address: Jahodova 3, Bratislava
    Beginning of reservation: 20210204
    End of reservation: 20210302
    ----------------------------
    ----------------------------
    Room number: 203
    Number of beds: 1
    Price: 103.52
    Guests:
    Name: Michal Novak
    Address: Malinova 97, Bratislava
    Beginning of reservation: 20210114
    End of reservation: 20210119
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're updating `head` and `gstHead` every time you insert Room and Guest, you always get `head` and `gstHead` as the last element you've inserted.

Update `head` and `gstHead` only once so that they point head of the linked list. To do so, do the following:

```
if (head == NULL) {
    head = hotelRoom;
}
// ...
if (gstHead == NULL) {
    gstHead = gst;
}
```

Also this logic is wrong:

```
hotelRoom->next = head;
gst->next = gstHead;
```

which should be changed to

```
tail->next = hotelRoom;
gstTail->next = gst;
```

with separate `tail` and `gstTail` pointers (which should be updated as `hotelRoom` and `gst` as well)

Also, to print all guests in the room, just make your `printGuest()` function take a parameter as the head of Guest linked list and traverse it. Don't use global variables.